# How to set footer below float component?

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer, sticky-footer

I have a sticky footer at the end of the web, but on one page where I have a Twitter feed inserted it does not work as I would like. The footer traverses the Twitter feed instead of being located below.

This is the code of the text and the Twitter feed:

```
<div>   
    <div style="float:left;width:80%;padding-right:20px">
        La Plataforma de Prácticas Externas..
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;position:absolute;display:inline-block;">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="es" data-width="300" data-height="800" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/X?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by X</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is the code of the footer:

```
<div  align="center" style="position: sticky;width: 100%;bottom: 0%;clear: both;padding-top: 20px;">
    <hr />
    <p class="small">Copyright &copy; <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" /> Footer </b>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

What I want to achieve is that the footer is located below the Twitter feed box

EDIT:

With @Sathiraumesh answer the result is:

[image: result2]

The preview I'm looking for would be something like this:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `postion: absolute` in this code off your application

```
<div style="float:right;position:absolute;display:inline-block;">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="es" data-width="300" data-height="800" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/X?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by X</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
```

also remove `position: sticky` from the footer

```
<div align="center" style="position: sticky;width: 100%;bottom: 0;clear: both;padding-top: 20px;">
        <hr />
        <p class="small">Copyright &copy; <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" /> Footer </b>
    </div>
```

to bring the twitter box in front add `z-index:3` in twitter box

```
<div style="z-index:3;float:right;position:absolute;display:inline-block;">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="es" data-width="300" data-height="800" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" href="https://twitter.com/X?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by X</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Doing it the Twitter box is placed under the text and on the right, and the footer is always visible at the end of screen no matter if I scroll

Comment: remove property  postion:sticky  from the  footer

Comment: Some improvement here. The footer is at the end now, but the Twitter box is still under the text

Comment: can you send me a preview

Comment: maybe you could use z-index:3 property to bring the twitter box  in front of the text

Comment: I edited with the result for your answer, the z-index:3 doesn't change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192837/discussion-between-sathiraumesh-and-atila665).

Comment: add width:70%  to the   La Plataforma de Prácticas Externas.. paragraph and remove the  padding-right:20px" in it  and add width:30%  to Twitter box make sure to change the width according to your preference changing the size make sure the addition of percentages =100% that is 70+30